# Require.js: Load dependency found outside of baseUrl

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I have a require.config.js file that looks like this:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/some/path',
  paths: {
    module1: '../../path/to/my/module'
  }
});
```

Why does the following work:

```
define(function(require) {
  const module1 = require('module1');
});
```

But this doesn't?

```
require(['module1'], ...);
```

When I run the above, it tries to load the dependency from the baseUrl and errors out:

```
require.js:168 Uncaught Error: Script error for "module1"
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
    at makeError (require.js:168)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1735)
```

Not even sure if this is the right question to ask. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Give your require.config I believe you would need this

```
require(['module1/module1'], ...);
```

So basically you need to include the defined path to the required file.

Comment: How would I do this if my defined path is not within my baseUrl directory?

Comment: `paths:` is for exactly that purpose.  `paths:` are assumed to be relative to `baseUrl`. So `module1: '../../path/to/my/modules'` means the folder up two from baseUrl and then down `/path/to/my/modules/`